# Putting called delegate into AsyncState parameter - Pros/cons?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message, string title, StatusType type, DateTime timestamp);
    IAsyncResult LogAsync(string message, string title, StatusType type, DateTime timestamp, AsyncCallback callback);
    void EndLogAsync(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

Implemented as a file-based logger...

```
...

    public FileInfo LogFileInfo { get; internal set; }

    public void Log(string message, string title, StatusType type, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            CheckLogFileSize(); //rotates LogFileInfo through numbered log files

            using (var stream = LogFileInfo.AppendText())
            {
                stream.WriteLine(GetFormattedString(message, title, type, timestamp));
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public IAsyncResult LogAsync(string message, string title, StatusType type, DateTime timestamp, AsyncCallback callback)
    {
        var action = new Action<string, string, StatusType, DateTime>(Log);
        return action.BeginInvoke(message, title, type, timestamp, callback, action);
    }

    public void EndLogAsync(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ((Action)result.AsyncState).EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

Notice the AsyncState parameter of BeginInvoke; I pass the delegate to its own invocation, so that I can reference it again on the flip side to end the invocation using the same delegate reference I called BeginInvoke on.

The questions:

- Is it even necessary to keep the actual invoked delegate reference around, or can I simply new up another reference to that method in the EndLogAsync method?
- Is this an acceptable use of the AsyncState, given that I have no other use for it?

Comment: Is there any chance you're writing on .NET 4.5? And why not use existing logging solutions (NLog, log4net)?

Comment: I think the implementation as it stands is the "most correct" using delegates/BeginInvoke/EndInvoke. Let it ride.

Comment: I really think that `LogAsync` should return a `Task` and therefore not accept a callback delegate. The APIs that consist `Begin*`/`End*` method pairs are ancient. By using `TPL` you can also let the implementers of `ILogger` interface use the new `async` features in .NET 4.5 more easily.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

- you can access the delegate instance by reading `((AsyncResult)asyncResult).AsyncDelegate` property (see `Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes` section of [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)). But it will be easier to cache the instance of the delegate in a readonly field and use it in both methods.
- yes, you can use AsyncState however you want, and sometimes people use it for passing the delegate being invoked

Note that you're using a separate thread (on a threadpool) each time you write something to log, so there will be contention between multiple threads if you write to log quickly enough. I would recommend using existing logging frameworks like [NLog](http://nuget.org/packages/nlog) or [log4net](http://nuget.org/packages/log4net) to avoid inventing a wheel.